# Multiplexer not processing second Input Processor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Using Scene2d, I have an InputMultiplexer that I create in my screen class. In my screen class I create my Stage and add it to the InputMultiplexer. I also create a group that handles the UI. I add the UI group to the stage. Then I add the group to the Multiplexer.

At this point the multiplexer has the stage in first, and then the UI group second.

My stage overrides the touchdown method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
  return false;
}
```

Because my stage is first in the multiplexer, it should handle the input first and since it returns false. It should then move to my UI group which has click listeners on various widgets. However, the UI group is never handled. If I remove the touchDown method on my stage, it works fine.

How can I get the UI group to also handle the input?

I also added the following methods to my stage class to see if it would help but it did not.

```
 @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: could you please share your code of Implementing UI group and adding it to the input processor?

Comment: It might be that the actors you add to your stage have their own event handlers that are handled before the stage. There is not enough information to conclusively say what the problem is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the event processing functionality of the Stage.
Check the source code of [Stage.touchDown](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java).

If you really want to override touchDown, override it with super call, **Be aware** that this might cause odd behaviors, because in the super function the eventhandling happens by Actors.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
  super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like the best way to avoid this would be to avoid overriding touchDown on the stage and handle my logic in a different way. I don't fully understand why it matters though. If I'm overriding the touchDown method, but returning false, shouldn't the MultiPlexer still move on to the UI Group which is second in the MultiPlexer?

Comment: Yes, I think you shouldn't override that. The source code is complex, but if you check it you can see that the event created by touchDown is fired with the root Actor if no other Actor is hit. But I don't know what happens when root doesn't fire that event.